# Finding the maximum distance from origin of a point on the curve $x=a\sin t-b\sin\left(\frac{at}b\right), y=a\cos t-b\cos\left(\frac{at}b\right)$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

**Question:**

Find the maximum distance from origin of a point on the curve $x=a\sin t-b\sin\left(\frac{at}b\right), y=a\cos t-b\cos\left(\frac{at}b\right)$, both $a,b\gt0$

**My Attempt:**

Applying distance formula,

$D^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(t-\frac{at}b)$

For maximum distance, cosine should be minimum i.e. $-1$. Thus, maximum distance is $a+b$.

But the answer given is $a-b$.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think $a+b$ is  the correct  answer. Perhaps they are minimizing the distance instead of maximizing it.

Comment: @geetha290krm thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D(t)$ be the distance of point P from origi On. Then
$$OP=D(t)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2-2ab\cos c t}, c=(b-a)/a,~ a,b>0$$
$D(t)$ will admit maximum value when $ct=\pi$, hence $D_{max}=a+b.$